# Is there a method of linking your Ubuntu account to your Ubuntu One/Social Network?

Tags: online-accounts, social

When I use my android device, I can sync my contacts from Facebook and twitter with their photos et al. I've also been using the Windows 8 developers preview recently which links into your Windows Live account. Is there any method to do something similar in Ubuntu? or are there plans to do so in later releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sub-questions can be answered with a yes. Gnome 3.x (which is what Ubuntu 11.10 and up are based on) has online-accounts, which currently supports linking with Google, but will add other services, and Ubuntu One, Software Centre, and any other Ubuntu-specific apps will use your Ubuntu-Single Sign On.